# how to create self hosted playwright trace viewer

Tags: playwright, e2e

how do I create https://trace.playwright.my.local ?

as of now trace itself is not static website itself and requires some pre-processing
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build and run this react site:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/tree/main/packages/trace-viewer

Answer (score 1):

You can try opening the saved trace using the [Playwright CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/c8487624dc00b33b4de870a45a7d33bfcfd4a44d/docs/src/trace-viewer.md#viewing-the-trace). For example, [here is a tutorial](https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer-intro) on how to use the trace viewer locally.

Essentially:

```bash
npx playwright show-trace trace.zip # with a zip
npx playwright show-report # show report after running `npx playwright test --trace on`
```

will end up displaying this:

[image]

Comment: I know, question is how to setup .local website to secure sharing debug links

Comment: Then if you have the website its as simple as forwarding that website -- you can try using a reverse proxy such as caddy or nginx but product recommendations are outside of the scope of StackOverflow.